# Create Word document of complete list (multiple list items)

Tags: list, ms-word, sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

I have a Sharepoint 2010 Custom List. I have created a Nintex Workflow to get all the data from the list i need and wrote it into a variable that contains a HTML table. Unfortunatelly Word only sees the code and not the table when i use this variable in a Content field in Word.

What i need is a way to get the filtered items of the list into a Word document (template) as a table.

I know how to do it with a single List Item but not for the complete list. With the Single item it works great with Content Controls but not for multiple items.

We use Sharepoint 2010 and Nintex. My knowledge of JS is zero and we are not allowed to use SPD.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with nintex workflow. You need to create a custom workflow using visual studio to achieve this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an HTML file via a Build String and Web Request (w/ PUT) actions. Then use the Convert Document action to convert it into a Word doc.